# Adding Process ID EventData to event log

Tags: mfc, event-viewer

I need to add some event data (e.g. Process Id) properties when reporting events.
I know there's a way to do that because I see other event logs having these props (See the Execution tag under System tag for example).
Do I need to add something to the Message Text File? or maybe some missing parameter when calling ReportEvent()?

```
  <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
      <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Winsock-AFD" Guid="{########-####-####-####-############}" /> 
      <EventID>1001</EventID> 
      <Version>0</Version> 
      <Level>4</Level> 
      <Task>1001</Task> 
      <Opcode>15</Opcode> 
      <Keywords>0x8000000000000005</Keywords> 
      <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-09-26T06:39:58.362482700Z" /> 
      <EventRecordID>15202</EventRecordID> 
      <Correlation ActivityID="{########-####-####-####-############}" /> 
      <Execution ProcessID="2768" ThreadID="4068" /> 
      <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-Winsock-AFD/Operational</Channel> 
      <Computer>Tsiki</Computer> 
      <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
    </System>
    <EventData>
      <Data Name="EnterExit">1</Data> 
      <Data Name="Location">2001</Data> 
      <Data Name="Process">0xfffffa800ec32b10</Data> 
      <Data Name="Endpoint">0xfffffa8008f9f2f0</Data> 
      <Data Name="Status">0</Data> 
    </EventData>
  </Event>
```

The project is written in C++/MFC.

Thanks